# JQueryUI model not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

First time I am using JqueryUI.

I am trying to pop a conditional modal to alert the user.

In my ajax call I have the following code:

```
.done(function (result) {
     $('#reportData').append(result);               
     var totalColumns = '@(ViewBag.TotalColumns)';
     if (totalColumns > 10) {
        callDialog();
     }
     else {
        print();
     }
})
```

The callDialog function is:

```
function callDialog() {
        $("#dialog-message").dialog({
            modal: true,
            draggable: false,
            resizeable: false,
            position: ['center', 'top'],
            show: 'blind',
            hide: 'blind',
            width: 600,
            dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-osx',
            buttons: [{
                text: "OK",
                click: function () {
                    print();
                }
            }, {
                text: "Cancel",
                click: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }]
        });
    };
```

The HTML for the modal is:

```
<div style="margin-left: 23px;">
    <p>
        Some Text
    </p>
</div>
```

The issue I am seeing is the the modal appears, but then quickly goes away and the print() is then called.

I would expect the modal to appear and if the user clicks the OK button the print() would fire off and if the user clicks the cancel it woudl just close the modal.

Comment: I believe the issue is here..  When the screen loads I see the print getting called from the OK button, even though the dialog has not been clicked.
            buttons: [{
                text: "OK",
                click: function () {
                    print();
                }

Answer (score 1):

From the API documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons

The way you are using the button option is not correct.
Here is the working snippet:

```
buttons: [{
  text: "OK",
  click: function () {
    print();
  }
}, {
  text: "Cancel",
  click: function () {
    $(this).dialog("close");
  }
}]
```

Comment: I still get the same results.

Comment: 1) you edited your question with my answer.. thats uncool and not very clever, especially if its not working for you 2) Here the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kg0gpqee/ its working on my side

Comment: Sorry,  I did make annotation that I did it.  I will know not to do that in the future.

Comment: I do see that your example is working.  While it's not the same example that I have, it does lead me to believe there is something wrong the way I am calling the function in the ajax call.